# How to delete old account app detail from Archives list in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using multiple client Apple developer account to in my `XCode` to code sign client app and after client app live I will remove client account from `XCode` preferences but its not removing all related app to client from Archives list in `XCode -> Organizer`.

strange issue so how can I remove that app from my Xcode archieve list ?

Ref Screen Shot :

[image]

I think its caching some where in local data of our MAC but dont know where ?

I have already clean all cache and derived data from MAC.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just images of application that was ever installed or synced with developer account and will shown here even after you remove all archives from `XCode`.

**To delete the archives:**

> GoTo -> XCode Preferences -> Click on the arrow just ahead of Archives: -> Remove them

Now you will no longer see the archives but app image still be there.
So if you don't want to see them as well.

**To delete the app image:**

> GoTo -> XCode Preferences -> Click on the arrow just ahead of Archives: -> **Products** -> Choose Your application bundle id -> Remove

[image]

Close organizer window and open it again. You will see the changes.

Comment: No I am not confused as its list of app which my client already published from other XCode and I don't want that app list in my XCode and as I said I have already cleared archive list but list app list is there so I want to remove that apps from XCode.

Comment: What does `Library->XCode->Products` folder contain? Those probably are there and once you delete them they will no longer appear in the list. These all are what you have in `Products` folder.

Comment: Yes I found one more folder named "Product" along with archive and there actually all app dump cached so I deleted that folders and it actually removed all app from archive list Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Delete from Organizer:

1. Right Click on `Archive (App)`
2. Select `Delete Archive...`

or

They are here: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` (Delete them this location) and then delete app images from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products`

Right Click on `Archive (App)` and select `Show in Finder` to go to `Archives` directory

[image]

If you remove all archive, it will remove your apps from Archive list.

Here is snapshot with Xcode 9.4 (beta 2). I removed all archives and app list became empty.

[image]

Comment: I know how to delete Archive but what I wrote in my question is I want to remove apps from archive list and I am unable to do so.

Comment: yes you are right but when above things is done while you haven't sync your developer account in your XCode as and when you sync your developer account with XCode it will show all apps which is already uploaded on iTunes and that app haven't build through your XCode so there is no archive in that app and thats why its not removing that apps from list form more detail check my attached screen shot.

Comment: @kunal good point in your updated answer I found one more folder named Product and there I can see many folder named with app identifier and I have tried to delete one of that folder and its removed app from that achieve list thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: @CodeChanger I already mentioned `Products` folder in my answer before krunal.

Comment: Yes actually i found it later as i only seen Archive folder so sorry for that @TheTiger

Comment: @Krunal Thanks! Actually you already have much repo. Let me gain few as we belong to same community `jungle` (Tiger + Lion). I'm curious for 10k repo. ;) Just Kidding!!